# nlargest() on indexed series doesn't return the result from each index

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe of election candidates, donors' occupation, and donated(received) amount. 
And, I am trying to find out the top 7 largest amount received by each candidate.

```
candidate name = cand_nm
donors' occupation = contbr_occupation
received amount = contb_receipt_amt
```

So I first grouped the dataframe by candidates' name and donor's occupation, and add up donation amount using .sum()

```
grouped = df.groupby(['cand_nm','contbr_occupation'])['contb_receipt_amt'].sum()
```

Then, I use nlargest() as below, but it returns top 7 amount from the entire series, not from each group. How can I calculate top 7 donation amount from each group?

```
grouped.nlargest(7)
```

Another question is "grouped" variable appears to be an indexed series. But when I print out its index using `grouped.index` It doesn't return "cand_nm" or "contbr_occupation". Am I wrong to think that this is an indexed series?

[image]

Comment: for future reference it is better if you can create a sample dataframe (as code or text) for testing and an expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SeriesGroupBy.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) with `group_keys=False` for avoid duplicated level of `MultiIndex`:

```
s1 = grouped.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(7)
```

Or use [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
s1 = grouped.sort_values(ascending=False).groupby(level=0).head(7)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'contbr_occupation':list('abcdef'),
        'cand_nm':list('aaabbb'),
        'contb_receipt_amt':[7,8,9,4,2,3]
})

grouped = df.groupby(['cand_nm','contbr_occupation'])['contb_receipt_amt'].sum()

s1 = grouped.sort_values(ascending=False).groupby(level=0).head(2)
print (s1)
cand_nm  contbr_occupation
a        c                    9
         b                    8
b        d                    4
         f                    3
Name: contb_receipt_amt, dtype: int64

s1 = grouped.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(2)
print (s1)
cand_nm  contbr_occupation
a        c                    9
         b                    8
b        d                    4
         f                    3
Name: contb_receipt_amt, dtype: int64
```

Last for `DataFrame` add [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = s1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  cand_nm contbr_occupation  contb_receipt_amt
0       a                 c                  9
1       a                 b                  8
2       b                 d                  4
3       b                 f                  3
```